# Have an image stick out of footer

Tags: css, html

I am working on a project for a class and have an issue.

The site can be found here: http://ispace.ci.fsu.edu/~seb10/cgs2821/proj10

What I have now is a div that I have positioned towards the bottom using inline styling in the HTML and a div.

It appears fine right now, but of course that depends on the browser that is being used.

I would like that image to always appear at the bottom without having to use inline styling. Essentially, I would like it to stick out of the footer, but not have anything else be affected or moved.

What would be the process to do this, if it is possible?

Here's a link to the CSS: http://2011.ispace.ci.fsu.edu/~seb10/cgs2821/proj10/style.css

Thank you very much for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is place the image with position absolute. I have moved the mast illustration to the footer: http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/98PLA/
Does this solve your problem?

```
#footer .container {overflow: visible;} /* use a different technique to wrap floated elements so you can place image in the footer and have it stick out - see underneath */
.fltright {position: absolute; bottom: 56px; right: 0;}

/* For modern browsers */
.container:before,
.container:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.container:after {
    clear:both;
}
/* For IE 6-7 (trigger hasLayout) */
.container {
    zoom:1;
}

    <div id="footer">
        <!-- Begin Container -->
            <div class="container">
                <img class="fltright" src='http://2011.ispace.ci.fsu.edu/~seb10/cgs2821/proj10/images/derrick.png' alt="derrick" width="300"/>
                <h1>Copyright &copy; 2013 <br />All Rights Reserved</h1>
                <h3><a href="mailto:seb10@my.fsu.edu">Webmaster</a> |<a href="#">Site Map</a> | <a href="about.html">About</a></h3>
            </div>  
            <!-- End Container -->
    </div>  
    <!-- End Footer -->
```

Comment: This works great. However, I did run into a problem where my personal image on the About page is now pushed up and shoved under the header.

Also, I'm not too worried about this not working on the Google Chrome browser for iPad, but the footer because larger and the image becomes unseen because they share the same color. Any idea why it doesn't work? Other than that, this has been helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Never mind, I fixed my about page... I forgot that you edited the .fltright, which affected that image. Just needed to make it a .fltright2 and change the HTML. That fixed it. Still curious about the iPad Google Chrome issue... because it works fine on the iPhone Google Chrome app... weird. Maybe the app has issues.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the oil well tower image is the one to be positioned.  I would create a .png file with a transparent background and then set it as background image to the .container element.

The .png transparency will allow the other background motif to show through in the open spaces (transparent) sections of your vector image.

This works fine as long as your footer elements flows right after your container element.

Answer (score 0):

To make an image ignore it's parent element, a combination of positioning and z-index can be used:

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
```

You can also try playing around with the `display` and `overflow` properties depending on exactly what you want it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

When I looked at your code, I came up with these css values to absolutely align your `.sidebar` on your page.  You had `position: relative;` to position it, however, it moves *relative* to how the large the window is and the surrounding elements.  This is why it was probably moving around.  However, `position: absolute;` does not consider surrounding elements and therefore will stay put.

```
.sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 233px;
    right: 10px;
}
```